# Airflow Relative Importing Outside /dag Directory

Tags: python, airflow

I haven't been able to move common code outside of the dag directory that airflow uses. I've looked in the [airflow source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/4f20f607764bb3477419321b5dfd0c53ba1db3c0/airflow/models.py#L272) and found [imp.load_source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source).

Is it possible to use `imp.load_source` to load modules that exist outside of the dag directory? In the example below this would be importing either foo or bar from the common directory.

```
── airflow_home
     |──── dags
     │   ├── dag_1.py
     │   └── dag_2.py
     ├── common
         ├── foo.py
         └── bar.py
```

Comment: does all these folders part of same app-module? or different modules. just in case all are from same app module you can use relative path to import.

Comment: @Haranadh yes. I updated the diagram to show the airflow_home directory.

Comment: I could not answer in comments. I posted my detailed answer. if you like it. please upvote. :)

Comment: A workaround by modifying the PYTHONPATH is posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154139/1881080

Answer (score 10):

Just add `__init__.py` files in all 3 folders. it should work.
Infact every folder in my folder structure having `__init__.py`. I could run the code and see output.

Example folder structure could be as:

```
── airflow_home
     ├── __init__.py
     |──── dags
     │   ├── __init__.py
     │   ├── dag_1.py
     │   └── dag_2.py
     ├── common
         ├── __init__.py
         ├── foo.py
         └── bar.py
```

and **dag_1.py** code can be as:

```
from stackoverflow.src.questions.airflow_home.common.bar import bar_test

def main():
    bar_test()

main()
```

I'm running this piece of code from my `pycharm`.
Your `airflow_home`'s folder path in my pycharm is `stackoverflow/src/questions/airflow_home/`

And **bar.py** code is

```
def bar_test():
    print "bar hara"
```

Comment: mine airflow home path is /usr/local/airflow... the from statement is like: "from usr.local.airflow" ... It claims an error "no module name usr". What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

Other way instead of adding `__init__.py` file is to add the following include at the top of dag script:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Add your airflow home path to **PYTHONPATH**

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same problem, this fixed it for me:

import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),os.path.pardir)))
from common.foo import *

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I'm running airflow on docker by the way:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.environ["AIRFLOW_HOME"]))
```