# Run DAG inside airflow container works fine but gets the AirflowException("Bash command failed") when triggered from Web

Tags: python, django, airflow

If I run the DAG inside the docker container with `airflow run dag_A task_1 ...` command, it works fine. But if I trigger the same DAG via the web-UI, it will fail with the following error:  `AirflowException: Bash command failed`. Sifting through the error logs, revealed this error `ImportError: No module named some-lib` where `some-lib` is a local module inside the dag folder. I think the error is related to this question posted in SO - [Apache Airflow DAG cannot import local module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998552/apache-airflow-dag-cannot-import-local-module)

I added the `__init__.py` files in the dag folder and sub-folders but did not seem to help. I also set `ENV PYTHONPATH=<path-to-dag>:${PYTHONPATH}` in Dockerfile but did not work as well.

Comment: Try doing the by manually adding the path to the dag folder in your DAG file using `sys.path.append(os.environ[...])` instead.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Can you expand a little bit on this?

Comment: Inside your DAG file, do `sys.path.append(path_to_somelib_folder)` then import your local module.

Comment: Usually the DAGs are in `os.environ['AIRFLOW_HOME']`.