# Airflow - Import from parent folder

Tags: python, airflow

Brief: I can run a dag by `$ python my_dag.py` but by Airflow UI it claims  the error `No module named 'my_file_to_be_imported'`.

I have a container with a `dags` and `lutils` (custom folder from mine) git folders maped as volumes inside airflow home as:

```
── airflow_home
     |──── dags
     │   ├── __init__.py     
     |   ├── my_dag.py
     ├──── lutils
         ├── __init__.py
         ├── my_file_to_be_imported.py
```

The `my_dag.py` file inside `dags` folder needs to read the content from `lutils` folder.

The `my_dag.py` (simplified) is defined as below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from lutils import my_file_to_be_imported

def do_something():
    my_file_to_be_imported.beauty_imported_method()

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_generate',
    python_callable=do_something,
    dag=dag)

my_file_to_be_imported.beauty_imported_method() #to check if python runs
print (my_file_to_be_imported.var) #to check if python runs
```

and the `my_file_to_be_imported` file inside `lutils` folder as:

```
def beauty_imported_method():
    with open('text.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write("test")
var = "my test var"
```

If I run by bash `$ python my_dag.py` (as a python script) it does execute the `beauty_imported_method` fine and prints the `var` variable.
But then inside airflow, there is a red warning saying: `Broken DAG: [path_to_airflow_home/dags/my_dag.py] No module named 'my_file_to_be_imported'`

How can I fix this to `airflow` understand my import as `python run` does?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070705/airflow-relative-importing-outside-dag-directory) very closed question in stackoverflow but dit not worked.

P.s.: this docker setup runs fine others dags which not rely on relative import.

Comment: How are `PYTHONPATH`, `AIRFLOW_HOME` in `airflow.cfg` and `path` setup?

Answer (score 0):

As @tobi6 mentioned, you should direct the two variable PYTHONPATH and AIRFLOW_HOME to the appropriate folder. In your case, i believe the PYTHONPATH is not set or incorrectly set.

It should be as following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/airflow_home
```